# Execute a Python script and capture its output to a file

Tags: tcl

I am trying to execute a Python script from TCL script and capture its output to a file:

```
set pythonScript [file join [file dirname [info script]] my.py]
exec py365 [file nativename $pythonScript] "arg1" > C:\\work\\my.log 2>@1
```

The Python script is called which has print statement but those are not getting redirected to `C:\\work\\my.log`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, I am afraid. Works for me, on macOS though. What Tcl version are you using (`puts $::tcl_patchLevel`)?

Comment: The above code will work… assuming you've got permission to write to that log file in that directory, and (covering the wild edge case here) that the Python code actually writes to standard out or standard error and doesn't access the terminal directly.

Comment: I am using TCL 8.5 - I found the issue, the issue was that stdin / stdout file handles were closed prior to this call in the script